# ASP.NET model binding: UpdateMethod not receiving data key

Tags: asp.net, gridview, model-binding

I am making a GridView with model binding, against a table with a single int primary key.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTimesheet" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        ItemType="BO.TimeSheet" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"
        DataKeyNames="TimeSheetID"
        SelectMethod="gvTimesheet_GetData" UpdateMethod="gvTimesheet_UpdateItem"
        OnRowDataBound="gvTimesheet_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
... // Note: TimeSheetID is NOT one of the columns here
```

The SelectMethod works fine, but the UpdateMethod

```
public void gvTimesheet_UpdateItem(int TimeSheetID) {
```

always gets the value 0 for the ID. The name of the parameter matches the DataKeyNames, which correctly matches the property of the model object for the key. Everything looks correct.

I tried adding the key as a non-visible BoundField, but that didn't make any difference so I removed it. It should be enough that it's in the DataKeyNames.

(The RowDataBound handler just populates a couple of DropDownLists/ComboBoxes for some other fields, doesn't do anything whatsoever with the key ID.)

What would make the key value fail to show up in the UpdateMethod?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, and it was an elementary mistake. My SelectMethod was getting a DataTable with the primary key value, but then it wasn't *populating that property* of the business object, `BO.TimeSheet.TimeSheetID`. So the model object was just retaining the default 0 value.

I guess when I wrote the gvTimesheet_GetData() method I was laboring under the impression that I only had to populate the fields I knew I wanted to be editable; that's obviously not the case.